# Probability problem with example

Tags: probability

Show that if an a sample space all results dont not have zero Probability, then the following mathematical property is is true:

$P(A\cup B) = P(A) + P(B) \implies AB= Ø$

Then find an example that the above property is not correct unless we demand that all possible results have not zero Probability

Comment: What do you know? What ideas do you have? What have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you know that $$P(A\cup B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A \cap B)$$ but for the hypothesis $$P(A\cup B) = P(A) + P(B) \Rightarrow P(A \cap B) = 0 \Rightarrow AB= Ø$$